# JavaScript: unexpected typeof result

Tags: javascript, this, typeof

I have an array iterator function:

```
function applyCall(arr, fn) {
  fn.call(arr[0], 0, arr[0]);
}
```

and some code

```
var arr1 = ['blah'];
applyCall(arr1, function (i, val) {
  alert(typeof this); // object    WHY??
  alert(typeof val); // string
  alert(typeof(this === val)) // alerts false, expecting true
});
```

Why is `typeof this` within the inline function `object` instead of `string`?

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/polshgiant/TYTkb/5/)

Comment: Just a note. I believe the last statement should be `typeof this === typeof val` instead of `typeof(this === val)`

Comment: Because `this` is not referring to the `arr1` anymore.  Once you use `this` in the function it referes to that `function` which is an object.

Comment: @icanc - That is not true. The first argument to `.call()` decides what `this` is inside the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a method is called in JavaScript, it internally sets `this` to the calling object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

> ...and primitive values will be boxed.

By "boxed," they mean that the primitive is wrapped in an Object.  Note that this only applies to the first argument to `apply`/`call`.  The other arguments become function parameters that are not "boxed."